# Ambiguous bit-field statement

Tags: c++, bit

The below `Note` seems to be `ambiguous` to me[found in a book of C++].

**It is possible to declare an unnamed `Bit-Field` to create padding in order to implement a specific object layout.**

What does the author want to convey from the above note?

I tried the following programs to understand but still not clear.`

```
class s
{
    public:
    unsigned  i:1;
};

int main()
{
    s x;
    x.i=1;
    cout<<x.i<<endl; //outputs 1
    return 0;
}
```

**How the program is working perfectly without giving any warning or error?**

I am using ideone[`C++ (gcc-4.3.4)`] : http://ideone.com/bLLz4

However, if i remove `unsigned` from the declaration, it gives the error:

```
prog.cpp:7: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘i’ with no type
```

**Another problem**

```
class s
{
    public:
    int i:1;
};

int main()
{
    s x;
    x.i=1;
    cout<<x.i<<endl; //outputs -1
    return 0;
}
```

**Does the output `-1` depend upon the machine architecture['Endianness']?**
**How the output is coming -1?**
http://ideone.com/XWbak

Comment: in 'unsigned i', the keyword "unsigned" is not the _name_ of the member, that's the type.  "i" is the name (which is indeed optional).  For the second, an signed int (on x86, unsure of others) has the same number of negative values as nonnegative values.  So for one bit, values are -1 and 0.

Comment: (Im going to bed. If anyone wants to extend that into a full answer feel free)

Comment: I have two questions. What two or more meanings are you finding in the 'ambiguous' quotation; and why do you think the code shouldn't compile and work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *unnamed* bit field, as the name implies, is one that has no name. Your `unsigned  i:1;` is not unnamed; its name is `i`. The name is optional; the type is not.

The C standard (I'll quote [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) says, in 6.7.2.1p12:

> A bit-field declaration with no declarator, but only a colon and a
>   width, indicates an unnamed bit-field. As a special case, a bit-field
>   structure member with a width of 0 indicates that no further bit-field
>   is to be packed into the unit in which the previous bit-field, if any,
>   was placed.

For example:

```
struct foo {
    unsigned int x:1;
    unsigned int  :0;
    unsigned int y:1;
};
```

Note that bit fields cannot be used to *reliably* specify object layout, since many aspects of their representation are implementation-defined.